# Can't include as <QtCore/QString>

Tags: c++, qt, qt-creator

In my project, QtCreator lets me do:

```
#include <QtCore> // include all core
#include <QString>
```

but not

```
#include <QtCore/QString>
```

I have a .pro file where I have `QT += core ...` so I don't know what is the issue. I looked at compile output and it appends `-I/path/to/qt/include/QtCore/` but want I want it to also add `-I/path/to/qt/include/`. I don't know what is the problem. I was using this exact project with Ubuntu 14.04 and now upgraded to 16.04. Now I am having this issue. My QTDIR is set, my Qt Kit is showing no strangeness etc.

Comment: What Qt version? 4.8 or 5.x?

Comment: Qt version is 5.7.1.

Comment: Why do you want to do `#include <QtCore/QString>` in the first place? The Qt-supported way of including its headers is just `#include <QString>`.

Answer (score 1):

Qt doesn't have documented that path to `include` dir is in include path while compiling. You shouldn't write `#include <QtCore/QString>`. You should write `#include <QString>` just like documentation says:

http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstring.html

If you really, really need, you can add this path to your include path manually in `.pro` file:

```
INCLUDEPATH += /path/to/qt/include
```

Comment: Shouldn't `<QtCore/QString> and <QString> work by default. The codebase uses the former and I have to adhere to it. And all was working fine before I moved on to Ubuntu 16.04.

Comment: @meguli I don't think Qt has ever supported includes in the style of `<QtCore/QString>`.

Comment: Then why was it working before? I didn't have `INCLUDEPATH += /path/to/qt/include` but it was seeing `<QtCore/QString>` properly.

Comment: @meguli It might have work but Qt documentation did never guaranteed this functionality. It is just undefined.

Comment: I don't know why they started like this in the first place but that's what I have. Can you direct me to the relevant portion of the documentation that saying this behaviour is undefined.

Comment: @meguli: documentation says nothing about this so it is undefined (by default) :)

Comment: I had reinstalled a new Qt 5.7.1 when I moved to 16.04. It was not working as you know. Now I copied and pasted my exact same kit from the 14.04 rather than installing anew. This one works with `<QtCore/QString>`. So somehow there is some config in there that makes this possible but I don't know what.

Comment: If such config exist, that is an undocumented feature. You should NEVER rely on those.